# Find if user watched 2 videos at the same time

Tags: python, arrays, list

So, assume we have following data, and we need to find if the user watched 2 videos at the same time, and the duration of that case:

```
history = [
    (5, 'StartVideo', 'Apes'),
    (20, 'StartVideo', 'Birds'),
    (66, 'StopVideo', 'Birds'),
    (70, 'StartVideo', 'Kangaroo'),
    (75, 'StopVideo', 'Apes'),
    (78, 'StopVideo', 'Kangaroo'),
    (160, 'StartVideo', 'Elephant'),
    (205, 'StopVideo', 'Elephant')]
```

Where: `(time, action, video name)`

As we are looking for the duration, the result for this particular example would be: `51 (Apes & Birds (20-66) and Apes & Kangaroo (70-75))`

I found only one solution: make array with all `StartVideo`s, then with 2 for loops find their `StopVideo`s and append them, and then make pairs using `combinations` from `itertools`.

```
starts = [[y, x[2], x[0]] for y,x in enumerate(history) if (x[1] == "StartVideo")]

for i,j in enumerate(starts):
    for k in range(j[0], len(history)):
        if (history[k][2] == j[1] and history[k][1] == "StopVideo" and len(j) < 4):
            j.append(history[k][0])

clear = [[x[2], x[3]] for x in starts]

c = combinations(clear, 2)
```

From this point, where we found all combinations, its easy to find the duration.

What do you think is the best and efficient way?

Comment: Just for clarification. In the data you shared, what would be the desired output?

Comment: @BuddyBob The duration of the case when user watched 2 videos at the same time

Comment: @wjandrea wow, thank you for editing

Comment: if your code works but you're worried about efficiency, you should post this to [Codereview site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead

Comment: So the desired result would be Apes & Birds (20-66) and Apes & Kangaroo (70-75)?

Comment: @NiK Welcome! Now, I tried running your code, but I got `IndexError: list index out of range` at `clear = [[x[2], x[3]] for x in starts]`. If you're looking for debugging help, please provide a [mre] including desired output and actual output (i.e. the error). If there's been a mistake and your code actually is working, it'd be better to ask on [codereview.se] instead. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: @jarmod yes, that's correct

Comment: What if a user watches three or more videos at once, what kind of output is expected?

Comment: @NiK OK, the error's gone away now, but it would still help a lot to add your desired output to the question.

Comment: @Grismar I'm not interested in case of three or more, because two will be enough to find that user did not followed instructions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that isn't very brief, but in my opinion readable and clear:

```
def generate_overlaps(history):
    watching = set()
    for time, action, video in history:
        # assuming a complete history, so no stopping of videos that weren't started
        if action == 'StopVideo':
            if len(watching) > 1:
                yield False, tuple(watching), time
            watching.remove(video)
        elif action == 'StartVideo':
            watching.add(video)
            if len(watching) > 1:
                yield True, tuple(watching), time


def all_overlaps(history):
    overlaps = {}
    for started, watching, time in generate_overlaps(history):
        if started:
            overlaps[watching] = (time,)
        else:
            overlaps[watching] = (overlaps[watching][0], time)
    return overlaps


example_history = [
    (5, 'StartVideo', 'Apes'),
    (20, 'StartVideo', 'Birds'),
    (66, 'StopVideo', 'Birds'),
    (70, 'StartVideo', 'Kangaroo'),
    (75, 'StopVideo', 'Apes'),
    (78, 'StopVideo', 'Kangaroo'),
    (160, 'StartVideo', 'Elephant'),
    (205, 'StopVideo', 'Elephant')
]


print(all_overlaps(example_history))
```

Result:

```
{('Apes', 'Birds'): (20, 66), ('Apes', 'Kangaroo'): (70, 75)}
```

However, this breaks if someone could watch more than two videos at once - and it's unclear what kind of output is expected in that case.

If the question is simply: what is the longest period that a user watched more than one video at once, this would do:

```
def longest_overlap(history):
    overlap = 0
    start = 0
    watching = set()
    for time, action, video in history:
        if action == 'StopVideo':
            watching.remove(video)
            if len(watching) == 1:
                overlap = max(overlap, time - start)
        if action == 'StartVideo':
            watching.add(video)
            if len(watching) == 2:
                start = time
    return overlap


print(longest_overlap(example_history))
```

Result:

```
46
```

Note that this still assumes the history is complete and that ever video that was started, was also stopped at some point in the history.

Comment: Very neat! We do not need to consider three or more cases, two will be enough!

Answer (score 0):

Assume you only need Yes/No answer, here is how to improve your original O(N^2) code to O(NlogN). You can modify to show which 2 are watched at same time

```
#O(NlogN) this is not needed if your original data is sorted
history=sorted(history)
#O(N)
watchedAtSameTime=False
n=1
while n<len(history):
    if history[n][2]!=history[n-1][2] or history[n][1]!='StopVideo' or history[n-1][1]!='StartVideo':
        watchedAtSameTime=True
        break
print(watchedAtSameTime)
```

Comment: If that was the case all you'd have to do is find out if there are two `StartVideo` in a row anywhere, assuming you can't stop a video that wasn't started. But he also wants to know what were the videos and in what time window they played simultaneously.

Comment: Yes I over complicated the solution. Fixing that

Answer (score 0):

One technique that you might find interesting, and possibly helpful, is set intersection.

For example:

```
apes = range(5, 75 + 1)   # 5-75
birds = range(20, 66 + 1) # 20-66

overlap = set(apes).intersection(birds)
# result: {20, 21, 22, ..., 64, 65, 66}
```

Because you know the numbers are consecutive, you know the intersecting range is `[min(overlap), max(overlap)]`. Not suggesting this is optimal, but could be valuable.

Note: you have to add 1 to each StopVideo time (if it's inclusive).